# How to access nested model in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Using Aurelia, say I have a custom element `<panel>` and a view/view-model `InfoPanel`. `<panel>` has a close button in it, which should perform some action on `InfoPanel`, e.g. call the `close()` function.

**Panel.html**

```
<template>
    <h1>${headerText}</h1>
    <button click.delegate="close()">x</button>
    <content></content>
</template>
```

**Panel.js**

```
@bindable({name: "headerText"})
@bindable({name: "close"})
export class Panel {
}
```

**InfoPanel.html**

```
<template>
    <require from="./Panel"></require>

    <panel header-text="Info" close.bind="close">
        <!-- content here -->
    </panel>
</template>
```

**InfoPanel.js**

```
export class InfoPanel {
    close() {
        // At this point, "this" referse to the Panel, not the InfoPanel instance.
    }
}
```

When I try this, I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: close is not a function
>   getFunction @ aurelia-binding.js:2033
>   evaluate @ aurelia-binding.js:1395
>   callSource @ aurelia-binding.js:4842
>   (anonymous function) @ aurelia-binding.js:4867
>   handleDelegatedEvent @ aurelia-binding.js:2972

My assumption is that the context is unclear to Aurelia, or I'm missing something...

Comment: Try "ref", see here: http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.1.3/doc/article/cheat-sheet/5

Comment: Thanks. I don't quite follow how I'd use that to solve my issue. Can you provide an answer with an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to do is possible but there are a few gotchas -

Panel.html

```
<template>
    <h1>${headerText}</h1>
    <button click.delegate="close()">x</button>
    <content></content>
</template>
```

To get panel.html to bind to close we need to make it an anonymous function by default.  I am using ES7 class instance fields (a long name for class properties) but you can use the decorator as a class decorator as you are, provided you set it up correctly -

Panel.js

```
export class Panel {
  @bindable headerText = '';
  @bindable close = () => {};
}
```

You need to use `call` to pass a function reference instead of `bind` which tries to evaluate the expression -

InfoPanel.html

```
<template>
    <require from="./Panel"></require>

    <panel header-text="Info" close.call="close()">
        <!-- content here -->
    </panel>
</template>
```

InfoPanel.js

```
export class InfoPanel {
    close() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using `call` instead of `bind` fixed it. I had also fixed it by adding a self-referencing property to my VM (`this.vm = this`) and binding the `close` function in the view like `<panel ... close.bind="close.bind(vm)">` so `this` would be resolved correctly -- very messy! Your solution works great, thanks.